# Knockout and Back Button

Tags: knockout.js

I have a page with a left navigation which is build dynamically.

When the user clicks on the item of the navigation, it makes an ajax call, gets the content and then binds to the page using knockout.js. The content has links and other information.

When the user clicks on a link it navigates to another page, and when the user clicks the back button, it comes back without the information that was loaded ( on the left nav click ) .

I have been looking, there were some suggestion about history.js, and other info, but I did not really find a solution to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "another page" do you mean a complete reload of all the HTML, scripts, etc.? If so, you're going to lose any state that you've established inside the browser; that's just the way things work.

One workaround would be to use `localStorage` to save the information that you've loaded (or maybe just the URL where you loaded it from) after loading it, and check to see if it exists when you re-initialize after coming back.

Another possibility is to avoid the new page load and use a router for internal navigation. This won't work, however, if the new page isn't under your direct control.